# image export is returning grey scale image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using [Network Optix](https://www.networkoptix.com/)  Video management service. Using their application I am building a plugin. For my purpose I want to export frame as an image from a video. for that I used following code to convert to cv object and saving into my file.

```
cv::Mat img_color; 

cv::Mat img(
 videoFrame->height(),/*_rows*/
 videoFrame->width(), /*_cols*/
 CV_8UC1, //< BGR color space (default for OpenCV) /*_type*/
 (void*) videoFrame->data(0), /*_data*/
 (size_t) videoFrame->lineSize(0)); /*_step*/

 cv::cvtColor(img, img_color, CV_GRAY2RGB);


m_lastVideoFrameTimestampUs = videoFrame->timestampUs();
std::string file_path = "/var/www/html/images/"+std::to_string(m_lastVideoFrameTimestampUs)+".jpg";
cv::imwrite(file_path,img_color);
```

below screenshot is what I am getting on Network Optix client application.

[image]

But, this is what I am getting as an image file on my machine.

[image]

1. `cvtColor` doesn't have any effect on the image
2. I think, `CV_8UC1` argument should be modified so that I will get RGB image

EDIT - 1:

changes `CV_8UC1` to `CV_8UC3`

Result turned into 3 segments of image

[image]

Comment: Removed the C tag because C has no scope resolution operator.

Comment: Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but if you have a grayscale image in the first place then calling cvtColor isn't going to add any colour. cvtColor changes the *colour space*, it doesn't actually add colours to an image that doesn't have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CV_8UC1` means that it is 8-bit single-channel array, you are getting a grayscale image at first and you can not except `cvtColor` to get it colorized again. `cvtColor` which you used will convert the image to BGR but all the channels will be in same value so it will continue to seem as grayscale.

In this case you can use `CV_8UC3` which means that it is an 8-bit unsigned integer matrix/image with 3 channels(If your image in 3 channels)

Comment: I tried, instead of `CV_8UC1` I used `CV_8UC3`. cvtcolor throws error. `error: (-215) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function cvtColor`

Comment: Why you are still using ```cvtColor``` your image is already BGR no need to convert it again. Thats the reason of error

Comment: It looks interesting, I also saw like that results in the past but I am not sure about the exact problem. You can try the other array types also( CV_8UC4, CV_16UC3 etc.) but **data** and **step** lines also can be the reason I dont know what those lines exactly doing.

Comment: CV_8UC4  creates 4 segments and CV_16UC3 creates white color image. None of them is working

Comment: My opinion is that the problem can be related with the ```data``` and ```step``` lines. You can play with their zero(0) in paranthesis. Unfortunately, I dont have any idea about this problem, please let us know if you can fix it. Good Luck